# Prove $m\cos^2{\theta} + n\sin^2{\theta} < l \implies \sqrt{m}\cos^2{\theta} + \sqrt{n}\sin^2{\theta} < \sqrt{l} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

Prove that $m\cos^2{\theta} + n\sin^2{\theta} < l \implies \sqrt{m}\cos^2{\theta} + \sqrt{n}\sin^2{\theta} < \sqrt{l} $ for every $m, n, l >0$.

Comment: is the hypothesis true for every $\theta$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be found in

> LARSON, LOREN C., 1983: *Problem-Solving Through Problems*.
>   Springer-Verlag, p. 255, 267.

The author proposes two solutions: the first one is based on the [**Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysInequality.html); the second one on the [**arithmetic-mean−geometric-mean inequality**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). A third solution, which uses the **concavity of $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $**, is left as an exercise.

---

I will write here the solution based on the second method:

\begin{align*}  
(\sqrt{m}\cos^2{\theta} + \sqrt{n}\sin^2{\theta})^2 
&= m \cos^4{\theta} + 2 \sqrt{mn}\cos^2{\theta}\sin^2{\theta}+ n\sin^4{\theta} \\ 
& \leq m \cos^4{\theta} + (m + n)\cos^2{\theta}\sin^2{\theta}+ n\sin^4{\theta} \\ 
&= (m\cos^2{\theta} + n\sin^2{\theta})(\cos^2{\theta} + \sin^2{\theta}) \\ 
&= (m\cos^2{\theta} + n\sin^2{\theta})\\ 
&<l.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the reference and the hints. I'll try to solve the problem using all the methods.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: write
$$
\sqrt{m}\cos^2\theta+\sqrt{n}\sin^2\theta=(\sqrt{m}\cos\theta)\cdot\cos\theta+(\sqrt{n}\sin\theta)\cdot\sin\theta
$$
and look into the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).